# Problem with arrow keys and boot screen flickering

Tags: boot, keyboard

I own a Dell Inspiron 5521r laptop with

1. Ubuntu 18.04 operating system.
2. Amd and Intel integrated graphics card. (As you all know there is no use of amd card as Ubuntu no longer support integrated cards)
3. Intel i5, 1.8Ghz processor. 3337u

Problems I am facing

1. Arrow keys keep working on their own. For example, If i  read any PDF, automatically up arrow key take me to the first page.
2. While writting, left arrow key will take me to the beginning of line. Not able to write. Sometimes not even able to enter password(my password is short, so I have to enter in one go that too very fast).
3. It seems that up and left arrow key is getting freezed somehow.
4. Ubuntu boot screen flickers with logo and bunch of codes running in the background. Although there isn't any error in booting.

Things I tried

1. Reinstalling keyboard driver.
2. These issues started after installing some software's and extensions like (synaptics, hardinfo, Dropbox extension), I removed all of them.
3. Doing so resolved one issue i.e. earlier some keys used to get pressed more than once.
4. In BIOS, there isn't any keyboard issue, which means the problem is with software, rather than hardware.
5. Again same issue is in grub menu and tty screen. so i guess this bug has nothing to do with gdm3.
6. Reinstalled Ubuntu still arrow key problem. However screen flickering problem resolved.
7. Problem does not happen in guest account.

Comment: Have you got a solution for this? please share it, If yes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Linux supports hybrid switchable graphics, in your case, Intel and AMD. It is called vga_switcheroo. You need to use the proper AMD driver - radeon or amdgpu, amdgpu-pro.

As regarding jumping cursor, it may be related to libinput. [Ubuntu touchpad issues - mouse pointer jumps around](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894679/ubuntu-touchpad-issues-mouse-pointer-jumps-around)

You can also try "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration"

Comment: You should probably be a little bit more specific in your solutions as to make the solutions accessible to users with limited technical knowledge.