# Touchpad change in behaviour after sleep

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

First of all excuse my english, it might be far from perfect as it's not my first language.
So, for the problem : since some times now my touchpad behaviour changes as it awakes from sleep.

When I click on the touchpad (up&down/left&right) he then doesn't recognize if I put a second finger on it (so impossible to drag&drop unless I move the finger who clicked). 
The trackpoint (or a mouse) on the other hand works perfectly fine.
the cursor on the screen also tends to lag fastly when I move it with the touchpad.

My laptop is a Lenovo T440s with Ubuntu 16.04
RAM: 8Go
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4

kernel: 4.13.0-32-generic

[Synaptic touchpad version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssdtp.png)

I have already seen some reports of similar bugs (as this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367441/touchpad-acts-funny-after-sleep))but either nobody responds or the answer doesn't work.

I really hope someone here might be able to help me with this one as I really can't figure out where to search next.
Thank you in advance :).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I installed an old kernel (4.11.0-14-generic) and it seems to solve the problem.

```
apt-cache search linux-image-extra
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-4.11.0-14-generic
```

But it's not really a long term solution as the old kernel version isn't protected against Meltdown/Spectre and I will obviously have problems in the future.

Let's hope there is a new kernel version that doesn't bug soon or a patch for Lenovo's touchpad on the new kernel.

If you have an other solution or remark don't hesitate but as for now I consider the problem "solved".