# Touchpad not working after standby, disabling hid_multitouch works in a funny way

Tags: suspend, mouse, touchpad, lenovo, 21.10

My touchpad is not working after the laptop (Lenovo Miix) wakes up from standby. I did some digging and found a lot of solutions that unload and re-load modules like hid_multitouch.
For me it is not working, after loading the module again, the touchpad still does not work. I noticed however that while the hid_multitouch modul is disabled, the touchpad works - but it acts funny: Its scrolls all screens with just one finger and higlights text in the console window.
As soon as I modproble the hid_multitouch module again, it stops working completely again.

My laptop is a Lenovo Miix and dmesg shows the device as SIPODEV Lenovo HID.
I am using 21.10 with all updates installed, Kernel 5.13.0-22

Comment: Does this answer your question? [touchpad acts funny after sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367441/touchpad-acts-funny-after-sleep)

Comment: Hey, no. As I wrote disable and re-enabling the module does not work.