# Touchpad behaviour changes after hibernation on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: touchpad, hibernate, synaptics

When waking up from hibernation, the touchpad behaves different than before hibernation. It is usable, meaning I can move the cursor, use left and right click, scroll etc. but the behaviour changed. For example, the scrolling is inverted, no more three-finger middle click, touchpad stays active during typing (really annoying). But when I open the touchpad settings, they look unchanged. In addition, the touchpad is unresponsive to changes of the touchpad settings after hibernation. The behaviour returns to normal (like i set it) after reboot.

I tried the following which couldn't resolve the problem:

- deactivating and reactivating `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` (like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1423495))
- Installing `Synaptics` drivers (to use instead of the default `libinput` drivers) with `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and subsequent reboot*

I wanted to try `sudo rmmod i2c_hid` + `sudo modprobe i2c-hid` ([Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132237/1767613)) but the first command returned `rmmod: ERROR: Module i2c_hid is in use by: i2c_hid_acpi` and I don't know how to proceed here.

*Although this was an upgrade in my view, as `Synaptics` offers richer configuration options.

[Making Ubuntu recognize the touchpad as a mouse](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271982) is not an option for me, as I would lose even more functionality that way.

I am using an HP ProBook 450 G6 with Kubuntu 22.04.

Output of `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3081:00 06CB:826F Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA3081:00 06CB:826F Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Wireless hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of `xinput list-props 11`:

```
Device 'SYNA3081:00 06CB:826F Touchpad':
        Device Enabled (189):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (191): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (324):     1
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (325):       2.500000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (326):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (327):    12.500000
        Synaptics Edges (350):  53, 1279, 44, 784
        Synaptics Finger (351): 25, 30, 0
        Synaptics Tap Time (352):       180
        Synaptics Tap Move (353):       68
        Synaptics Tap Durations (354):  180, 180, 100
        Synaptics ClickPad (355):       1
        Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (356):  0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (357):    282
        Synaptics Two-Finger Width (358):       7
        Synaptics Scrolling Distance (359):     -31, -31
        Synaptics Edge Scrolling (360): 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (361):   1, 1
        Synaptics Move Speed (362):     1.000000, 1.750000, 0.127551, 0.000000
        Synaptics Off (363):    1
        Synaptics Locked Drags (364):   0
        Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (365):   5000
        Synaptics Tap Action (366):     0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
        Synaptics Click Action (367):   1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling (368):     0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (369):    0.100007
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (370):     0
        Synaptics Circular Pad (371):   0
        Synaptics Palm Detection (372): 0
        Synaptics Palm Dimensions (373):        10, 200
        Synaptics Coasting Speed (374): 20.000000, 50.000000
        Synaptics Pressure Motion (375):        30, 160
        Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (376): 1.000000, 1.000000
        Synaptics Resolution Detect (377):      1
        Synaptics Grab Event Device (378):      0
        Synaptics Gestures (379):       1
        Synaptics Capabilities (380):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
        Synaptics Pad Resolution (381): 12, 12
        Synaptics Area (382):   0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Soft Button Areas (383):      666, 0, 678, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Noise Cancellation (384):     7, 7
        Device Product ID (317):        1739, 33391
        Device Node (316):      "/dev/input/event11"
```

As you can see, the `Synaptics` drivers are now used instead of the `libinput` drivers before.

Comment: "Hibernation/sleep"  and Linux are a difficult thing because hardware manufacturers do not disclose all details about the hardware. Because of this, hibernation/sleep may have issues. There are however differences in "sleep"  versus "hibernation". While "hibernation"  may not work, "sleep" may. It is thus important that you are clear about whether one or both of these states gives the problem. "Hibernation" typically has issues more frequently, and therefore is disabled by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: @vanadium I actually meant hibernation (edited the question). The touchpad works fine after sleep. When I posted the question, I was not aware that sleep and hibernation mean different things because I am used to the german naming.